# How to join three tables or more than three tables if many ID is pointing from one table to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confused here about joining suppose I have three tables here Student table, Course table, Teacher table

'Student' table

```
Std_Id    Std_Name    Course_Id   Teacher_Id 
1         Amit         2           1
2         Yogesh       1           1
3         Pravin       3           2 
4         Nilay        1           3 
5         Abhijit      2           2
6         Vishal       2           4
7         Ramesh       3           3
8         Vijay        3           4
9         Ben          1           3
10        Vinod        2           4
```

'Course' table

```
Course_Id   Course_Name   Std_Id   Teacher_Id
1           JAVA           1        3
2           C#             1        3
3           C++            3        1
4           SAP            2        2
5           PYTHON         2        1
6          JAVASCRIPT      3        2
```

'Teacher' table

```
Teacher_Id  Teacher_Name  Std_Id  Course_Id
1           Roy            1       1
2           John           2       1
3           Ben            1       3 
4           Renu           2       3
5           Ramesh         1       3
```

As you can see I have three tables here so now I  want to see the  students who have courses and teachers so let`s look up here in the student table, we have Std_Id,Course_Id,Teacher_Id and in the Course table we have Course_Id,Std_Id,Teacher_Id and in the Teacher table we have Teacher_Id,Std_Id ,Course_Id so here I want to join three tables as I said I want to show students who have the courses and teachers then which column should be used here and here i am not giving any reference key so how  to join three tables i am giving query here

```
select Std_Name,Course_Name,Teacher_Name 
from   Student
inner join Course
        on ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._
inner join Teacher
        on ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._ 
        or ._=._
```

so which common column should be used here to join three tables please let me know guys please give me answer.

Comment: Please help me guys which one should be used common column here

Comment: please help guys

Comment: We can't answer your question because your table design does not make sense at all. The existing design says `One student can have only One Course and One Teacher`, `One Course is taken by One student and conduct by One teacher` etc.

Comment: @Squirrel this type of table design could be there in the organization?

Comment: Very unlikely. Reason is as stated in my previous comments

Comment: I have updated my data now could you please help me how can i choose column to join three tables

Comment: hey please help me someone how to join three tables if many ids pointing from one table to another table please help someone

Comment: @squirrel please help i have updated my data please help me dude

Comment: We can't help you because we don't understand your table design as it does not make sense at all. Maybe it make sense to you but not me. Perhaps you are approaching the problem wrong. Clarify the issue again with your lecturer